# New Ubuntu 18.04 install screen is very zoomed in. Zoom is off in universal access and I’m not sure how to fix this

Tags: 18.04, display-resolution

My entire ubuntu screen on my new install on a new PC is zoomed in. I have read other posts online and haven’t yet found anything that fixes this. Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!
The output of the terminal command `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`
Is as follows:

```
VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2486 (rev a1)
Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2486
Kernal modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
Audio Device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 228b (rev a1)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Thanks I have edited my question now :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Nvidia drivers.

Run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-driver-460
```

Reboot and disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: I did this but replaced the word ubuntu with nvidia after searching for solutions as the package could not be found, it installed however now I can’t get onto ubuntu at all it just shows a purple screen, any advice?